# How to make a do statement restart?

Tags: java, validation

I really do not know to how explain this but here we go.

I am testing something for a bigger program I have to make. In the program I have to validate input from the user to see if it is being to be accepted as a valid answer.

I have the code to where it will say if the input is invalid but if I attempted to enter another letter the code crashes with this error:

```
Enter a letter:
f
Your answer is not valid.
A
Enter a letter:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
    at example.main(example.java:18)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        boolean UserInput;

        do
        {
                char user_answer = 0;


                System.out.println("Enter a letter:");
                user_answer=input.nextLine().charAt(0);

                if ( user_answer == 'A')
                {

                    UserInput = true;
                }
                else if (user_answer == 'B')
                {

                    UserInput = true;
                }
                else if (user_answer == 'C')
                {

                    UserInput = true;
                }
                else if (user_answer == 'D')
                {

                    UserInput = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is not valid.");
                    UserInput = false;
                    input.next();
                }


        }

        while   (!UserInput);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either remove `input.next()` or change it to `input.nextLine()`
What's happening is that `input.next()` will catch the `A` you input. Then you go back to the beginning of the `do` and start over, and do `input.nextLine()` but you had already pressed `enter` to input `A` and the `A` was consumed by `input.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `input.next();` and it will work fine. The reason is because when you use `input.next()`, it reads the next character the user types, without exiting the line. Then when the `input.nextLine()` executes, it reads that same line, but immediately after the number. Since nothing is after the number, it reads in nothing "" and the `charAt(0);` becomes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Example
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


     boolean UserInput;

     do
      {
            char user_answer = 0;


            System.out.println("Enter a letter:");
           // user_answer=input.nextLine().charAt(0);
           user_answer=input.next().charAt(0);

            if ( user_answer == 'A')
            {

                UserInput = true;
            }
            else if (user_answer == 'B')
            {

                UserInput = true;
            }
            else if (user_answer == 'C')
            {

                UserInput = true;
            }
            else if (user_answer == 'D')
            {

                UserInput = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Your answer is not valid.");
                UserInput = false;
               // input.next();
            }


       }

        while(!UserInput);

     }

   }
```